# Yes, I do vs. Yes, I want to

Tags: word-choice

To give a short answer to a question with the verb ***want***, we say:

> Do you want to come with us?
>   -Yes, I do.

Is it also possible to say:

> Do you want to come with us?
>   -Yes, I want to.

Comment: Related question, [In reply to “Do they have…”, which is correct — “yes, they do” or “yes, they have”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/in-reply-to-do-they-have-which-is-correct-yes-they-do-or-yes-they-h/42942#42942). I would prefer answering the question with "Sure", "Of course", or "Why not". If there are only two choices, I would definitely use the auxiliary verb, **do**.

Comment: I've rarely seen a short answer with the second option. I don't know whether native speakers find it regular or unused. It'd be good to see an explanation since other examples can be shown as *Do you take your medication? — Yes, I take it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native speaker of American English, I would most likely say

> Yes, I  do.

I could be a little more emphatic and say

> Yes, I sure do.

If I wanted to use *want* I would most likely still use *do*:

> Yes, I do want to.

But I would not say that often, and usually only when some person or some circumstance has cast some doubt on whether I want to.

The other option

> Yes, I want to.

is not wrong, but it is probably the version I would least likely say. I may use it when I *want* to come but can't actually do so:

> Yes, I want to, but I can't.

---

Instead of *Yes, I do want to* I could also say

> Yes, I do do.

which means the same (emphasizing that I do actually want to go). However, this can be problematic, as *do do* sounds like *[doodoo](http://www.onelook.com/?w=doo+doo)*, which is a slangy, child directed, or childish synonym of *[poopoo](http://www.onelook.com/?w=poo+poo&ls=a)* (*[excrement](http://www.yourdictionary.com/poo-poo)*). So I wouldn't advise saying this unless you and the people you are talking with averse to any reference to this homonym, unless you wish to make a childish joke.

Comment: The "sure do" thing is fine but not really necessary. I speak AmE and rarely say that. And certain verbs in English allow for repeating the main verb + to in the answer so the auxiliary does not have to be used: Would you like to come to the movies? A: Yes, I'd like to but can't.  And "Yes I do want to" the emphatic form, is when there is some question about whether the person really wants to go. And "I do do" is a thing I have never ever heard in my entire life. What I have heard is: Yes, I do, I do.